# Iterate over keys of groups and write data to files

Tags: python-3.x, macos, geopandas

I am a total beginner in Python. I would like to iterate over the keys after groupby command, like in:

```
Groups = Country.groupby(['province_territory']).groups
for c in Groups: 
Region = Country[Country['province_territory'] == c]
print(c)
```

instead of the following approach I used:

```
A = gp.GeoDataFrame(Country[Country['province_territory'] == 'A'])
B = gp.GeoDataFrame(Country[Country['province_territory'] == 'B'])
C = gp.GeoDataFrame(Country[Country['province_territory'] == 'C'])
D = gp.GeoDataFrame(Country[Country['province_territory'] == 'D'])

A.to_file('DATA/A')
B.to_file('DATA/B')
C.to_file('DATA/C')
D.to_file('DATA/D')
```

Country is a geojson data file.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close you just need to iterate over the groups, querying the main DataFrame to get the subset DataFrame for each province territory. In a `DataFrame.query` clause the `@` character is used to include a variable. Since you're a beginner it's also worth mentioning what `f'DATA/{territory}'` does, it's a nice clean way to do string formatting in python3.6 and on. It'll insert the value of the variable territory at that position in the string.

```py
for territory in Country.groupby(['province_territory']).groups:
    df = Country.query('province_territory == @territory')
    df.to_file(f'DATA/{territory}')
```

By the way, if you just need the unique set of province territory values and nothing that the groupby method provides, a little cleaner version could be:

```py
for territory in Country['province_territory'].unique():
    df = Country.query('province_territory == @territory')
    df.to_file(f'DATA/{territory}')
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked pretty well for me, with little tweak in your code. I still need to treat it at geopandas Geodataframe:

    for territory in Country['province_territory'].unique():    
        df = gp.GeoDataFrame(Country.query('province_territory == @territory'))
        df.to_file(f'DATA/{territory}')